# Why the response.sendRedirect() in servlet doesn't work after receiving the post request of JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets, redirect

In the blog-edit.html, JQuery was used to send the post request to the sever side(java servlet).

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
                    $.post("/blog/handler",{"content":$('#textarea').val()},
                    function(data){
                        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                        if(data.toString().length>1){
                            alert("Saved!")
                        }else{
                            alert("Failed!")
                        }
                    })
```

In the server side:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String content = request.getParameter("content");
            System.out.println(content);

            response.sendRedirect("/blog/list");
            return;
    }
```

What I saw is the server side is printing the content from the html, and the alert window pops up to say "Saved!". But the redirect function doesn't work

After searching I have no choice but to use jquery to redirect:

```
if(data.toString().length>1){
                            alert("Saved!")
                            window.location.replace("/blog/list")
                        }
```

it works, but it's not what i want

please help

Comment: Is the servlet invoked?  Do you see your System.out.println(content)?

Comment: yes, i can see the output in the servlet

Answer (score 7):

While using ajax. you can not execute server side redirect.

However, there are better way how to redirect on client in such a scenario.

[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: While using ajax. you can not execute server side redirect. Why?!

Comment: that is how it is. You need to read something about it yourself. before using ajax.